# Can someone explain why the electrical conductivity of magnesium chloride decreases with increasing concentration?

Tags: electrochemistry, conductivity, salt

I was under the impression that the electrical conductivity should increase initially, then begin to plateau, then fall past the saturation point for strong electrolytes. However, from this, I see that the conductivity of magnesium chloride does not follow this ( it is decreasing with increasing concentration) , BUT the data could be wrong though. Would someone mind explaining what I should expect when I conduct the experiment myself?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 5):

You simply started your data range at too high a concentration to see the initial increase.  [Semantic Scholar](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cbc5/22cf4c5e6e690ca48984314c231f6643ee81.pdf) gives data for the conductivities of several aqueous electrolyte solutions at 25°C, including magnesium chloride.  The strongly increasing portion of the magnesium chloride curve goes up to about 10%, which corresponds to about one molar (where your data happens to start).

Comment: Not increasing at an increasing g rate.  Compare conductivities with the mass percents whose increments are non uniform (1%, 2%, 5%, 10%, etc.).  10% is just over 100 g/L including the increased density and the molecular weight of MgCl2 is 95.  Finally your trend at >1M is not very strong and its direction at a given concentration may be affected by measurement uncertainties.

Comment: If you want to go up to 1M what you choose is good.